# How can i pipe mysql data to a browser window instead of the console in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Hi I am currently trying to output mysql data to a browser window instead of the console, and I have not a clue on how to do this in Node, which I am quite new to.

Here is the mysql.js file:
'
var mysql = require ("mysql");

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user: "root",

});
 connection.connect(function (err) {console.log( "Successfully   Connected.");
    if (err) throw err;
 });


var query = connection.query("SELECT * FROM myTable", function (err, result, fields){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('result:', result);
});

connection.end();'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a server which you can connect to and receive data from with a browser. The most convenient and by far the simplest way to do this is HTTP. You can read about HTTP servers in node.js [here](http://blog.modulus.io/build-your-first-http-server-in-nodejs). The fist code snippet on that page demonstrates a HTTP server with one handler function, which is all you need to achieve your goal.

An (untested) example for convenience:

```
// Dependencies
var mysql = require("mysql"),
    http  = require("http");

// This holds our query results
var results;

// Connect to database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root"
});
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to database");
});
connection.query("SELECT * FROM myTable", function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    results = rows;
    connection.end(); // Disconnect from database
});

// Function to handle browser's requests
function requestHandler(req, res) {
   res.end(JSON.stringify(results)); // Respond to request with a string
}

// Create a server
var server = http.createServer(requestHandler);
// That magic number 8080 over here is the port our server listens to.
// You can access this webpage by visiting address http://localhost:8080
server.listen(8080, function() { 
    console.log("Server online");
});
```